# error when using time in rolling function pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate mean i.e moving average every 10sec of data; lets say 1 to 10sec, and 11sec to 20sec etc.

Is below right for this? I am getting error when using "60sec" in rolling function, I think it may be due to the "ltt" column which is of type string, I am converting it to datetime, but still the error is coming.

How to resolve this error? Also how to do the averaging for samples collected every 10sec. This is streaming data coming in, but for testing purpose, I am using the static data in record1.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

records1 = [
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:05 2022', 'last': 258},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:05 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:07 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:08 2022', 'last': 260},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:09 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:10 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:11 2022', 'last': 261},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:12 2022', 'last': 262},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:12 2022', 'last': 260},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:14 2022', 'last': 258},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:15 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:16 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:17 2022', 'last': 260},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:18 2022', 'last': 258},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:19 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:20 2022', 'last': 260},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:21 2022', 'last': 260},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:22 2022', 'last': 258},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:23 2022', 'last': 259},
{'ltt': 'Mon Nov  7 12:12:24 2022', 'last': 260}
]

datalist = []

def strategy1(record):
    global datalist

    datalist.append(record)
    pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(datalist)
    pandas_df['ltt'] = pd.to_datetime(pandas_df['ltt'], format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")

    pandas_df['hour'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.hour
    pandas_df['minute'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.minute
    pandas_df['second'] = pandas_df['ltt'].dt.second

    pandas_df['max'] = pandas_df.groupby('second')['last'].transform("max")

    pandas_df["ma_1min"] = (
        pandas_df.sort_values("ltt")
            .groupby(["hour", "minute"])["last"]
            .transform(lambda x: x.rolling('10sec', min_periods=1).mean())
    )

    print(pandas_df)
```

Comment: Seems like someone managed to figure out your issue without seeing the error. But for the next time, if you get an error, please include the error into the question. It typically contains very useful information about the issue you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know how to exactly implement this in your code but i had a kind of similar problem where i had to group each day into 4 hour timeslots. so an approach might be something like this:

```
pandas_df.groupby([pandas_df['ltt'].dt.hour, pandas_df['ltt'].dt.minute, (pandas_df['ltt'].dt.second / 10).astype(int)]).last.agg('mean')
```

this should basically give you 6 groups ([0s-9s -> 0], [10s-19s -> 1], etc. for the 3rd groupby index) for every minute of data.

Comment: Thanks.. For another scenario eg: moving averages for 0 to 10sec, 1sec to 11sec, 2sec to 12sec etc i.e for calculating running average every 10sec, i am trying to use "10sec" parameter in rolling method, but is giving problem. Please give suggestion if its used to ltt parameter is not having correct datetime format for the problem.

Comment: @vrreddy1234 hmm ok that's a different problem, there is a way to display datetimes as an integer maybe that could be what your looking for. after you do the rolling average you can simply convert it back into a readable format